# database pool with PGPoolingDataSource?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I'm having problems when I create a database pool with PGPoolingDataSource class, after a while the pool goes down when many users are working and shows no errors

The code of the class that creates the pool is:

```
public class PgConexion {
    private static PgConexion _instancia = new PgConexion(); // instancia de la clase
    private Configuracion config;
    private PGPoolingDataSource source;

    /**
     * instancia la clase y carga las opciones de configuracion
     */
    public PgConexion() {
        final URL archivo = Constantes.RUTA_CONFIG;

        if(archivo != null){
            config = new Configuracion(archivo);
        }
    }

    /**
     * regresa la instancia del pool de conexiones
     * @return
     */
    public static PgConexion getInstance() {
        return _instancia;
    }

    /**
     * crear la conexion la conexion
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void crearConexion() throws SQLException{
        source = new PGPoolingDataSource(); 

        // configuracion del pool
        source.setDataSourceName("Logistica");
        source.setServerName(config.get("servidor_sql"));
        source.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(config.get("puerto_sql")));
        source.setDatabaseName(config.get("bd_sql"));
        source.setUser(config.get("usuario_sql"));
        source.setPassword(config.get("contrasena_sql"));
        source.setMaxConnections(30);
    }

    /**
     * devuelve la conecion a utilizar
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public Connection nuevaConexion() throws SQLException{
        if(source == null){
            crearConexion();
        }

        // genero la conexion de la lista del pool
        return source.getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Cierra las conexiones y libera los recursos
     */
    public void cerrarConexion(){
        source.close();
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not a very good idea to use **PGPoolingDataSource**, as [JDBC documentation explains](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.html).

The base problem is that the call for **getConnection()** will be blocked until a connection is closed when the limit of connections has been reached.

You've set the value 30 as the max amount of concurrent conections, so if a 31st is intended to be opened, it will cause a block on the Thread making the call.

Possible solutions:

- Increase **maxConnections**, if you are certain about the real amount of concurrent connections upper limit.  You should also check the server-side connection limit in **postgresql.conf**.
- Use [PGSimpleDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html).  Depending on the type of application, not using a pool of connections (thus creating the connection each time) will not be a problem.
- If you really need a pool of connections, simply implement your own at Java level.

EDIT: You can check the amount of opened connections by simply running:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

Each row is a connection (including the one from pgAdmin and the query analyser).  If you are certain that the number of connections should not raise up to the upper limit (but nevertheless it does), maybe you are having some sort of connection leak problem.

Comment: Agreed; it's better to use a proper pooling system like DBCP, C3P0, or your app server / container's built-in connection pooling.

Comment: i was having a connection leak problem when reloaded the webapps in tomcat, that fixed the problem. also i will try BDCP

Comment: You mention that it is a problem if getConnection() blocks. It should be noted that in some cases that could be _exactly_ the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

If my experience pertains, the problem is probably not here, but rather that your clients aren't always closing their connections, for one reason or another - frequently, from forgetting to do so in error-handling scenarios.

The best way to deal with this varies with the scenario.  If the client is your own code, it's a lot different from when the client is code written by an unknown person in an unknown organization.